# Forwarding data as TCP Client

Tags: c, sockets, tcp, tcpclient

I have a client requesting data (DA) from server A, and then I need to send DA to a second server B. I got it while the data is not larger than the buffer. However the following is not working for passing all data from A to B. I notice that when I create the socket_fwd and connect after closing the first sockfd, it works. But since I need to forward all data, I need to process all incomming as soon as it arrives

```
    int sockfd, sockfd_fwd, n, n_fwd;
    gint BUFFER=900;
    char buf[BUFFER];
    char* addr = "11.0.0.20"; //Server A listening on port 80
    struct sockaddr_in server_addr = {0};
    server_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server_addr.sin_port = htons(80);
    char chunk[BUFFER]; 
    gint nfw;
    gint total_recv = 0;
    gint total_fwd = 0;
    struct sockaddr_in server_addr2 = {0};
   server_addr2.sin_port =  htons(5555);
   server_addr2.sin_family = AF_INET;
   char *addr2 = "127.0.0.1"; //Server B listening on port 555

   //#################Request data from A:80 ###########################
   if(inet_pton(AF_INET, addr, &server_addr.sin_addr) != 1){
       perror("inet_pton");
       return -1;
   }
   sockfd = socket(AF_INET, (SOCK_STREAM), 0); //socket with server A
   if (connect(sockfd, (struct sockaddr*)&server_addr, sizeof(server_addr)) < 0) 
   mylog(G_LOG_LEVEL_MESSAGE, __FUNCTION__,"Error on connect"); 
  send(sockfd, buffer, strlen(buffer), 0); //Buffer contains something like get xx Kib to the server
  bzero(buffer, BUFFER);      
  if(inet_pton(AF_INET, addr2, &server_addr2.sin_addr) != 1){
     mylog(G_LOG_LEVEL_MESSAGE, __FUNCTION__,"Error inet pton");
  return -1;
  }

  if(inet_pton(AF_INET, addr2, &server_addr2.sin_addr) != 1){
     perror("inet_pton");
     return -1;
  }
  sockfd_fwd = socket(AF_INET, (SOCK_STREAM), 0); //socket with server B
  if (connect(sockfd_fwd, (struct sockaddr*)&server_addr2, sizeof(server_addr2)) < 0) 
     mylog(G_LOG_LEVEL_MESSAGE, __FUNCTION__,"Error on connect");    

  while ((n = recv(sockfd, chunk, BUFFER, 0)) > 0) {
     total_recv += n;
     mylog(G_LOG_LEVEL_MESSAGE, __FUNCTION__,"Recv chunk %s num-bytes:%i",chunk,total_recv);
     nfw = send(sockfd_fwd, chunk ,n, 0);
     memset(chunk,0,BUFFER);
   }
   close(sockfd);
   close(sockfd_fwd);
```

Comment: If you recv [BUFFER] bytes, then 'chunk' is not guaranteed NUL-terminated and myLog(......%s.) will likely fail.

Comment: Get rid of the '%s' buffer dump, (which, even if you under-read or oversize the buffer to ensure there is a NUL at the end, will still not work correctly for general binary data with embedded NULs.), and you can then get rid of the near-useless memset call.

Comment: @MartinJames yes my '%s' are just to understand what was happening, but I will remove it. The question is more oriented to know if the sockets are well used

Comment: 'send(sockfd, buffer, strlen(buffer), 0);' presumably, you load 'buffer' somewhere or it's a const string.  How does the peer know it has received all the message?  You don't send the terminating NUL, and your comment does not suggest any other line-termination char,

Comment: 'know if the sockets are well used' looks OK to me - you recv 'n' bytes and send 'n' bytes in a loop until the recv() return indicates error or peer-close:  Assuming your 'command' message issue is solved, I would expect it to work.

Comment: Actually mylog does not fail, what does not work is send(...), because in the server I do not receive any byte. Now, I am trying only with alphanumerical char, and for testing the number is limited.

Comment: Well, send() returns a value.  You must correctly and completely handle the results returned from system calls like recv, send and, if an error is returned, check errno/GetLastError()

Comment: send() is correctly returning the number of processed bytes.

Comment: ...then they are on their way.  I assume then that your protocol with the server/s is at fault.  Wireshark it as you transfer a very small file?